# How can I add prefixes to ordered list item numbers in email?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, inline-styles

I need to make a list like:

```
question 1: ...
question 2: ...
question 3: ...
```

I know this is easily achievable in CSS with something like `li:before{content:"question "}`

But my use case is an html-email, so I am limited to inline styling only. I can't use classes and selectors. Is there a solution?

I would like to avoid repeating the word "question" for each list element in the code or break semantics otherwise.

---

Just FYI, This is how it should look like in my use case:
[image]

```html
<ol style="max-width:7cm">
  <li style="border:2px dotted rgb(187,187,187);padding:2mm;margin-bottom:3mm;background:#D8EDFF;border-radius: 20px;">Why is the sky blue ?</li>
  <li style="border:2px dotted rgb(187,187,187);padding:2mm;margin-bottom:3mm;background:#D8EDFF;border-radius: 20px;">How many teeth an adult human has?</li>
  <li style="border:2px dotted rgb(187,187,187);padding:2mm;margin-bottom:3mm;background:#D8EDFF;border-radius: 20px;">Why do birds fly south in the winter?</li>
  <li style="border:2px dotted rgb(187,187,187);padding:2mm;margin-bottom:3mm;background:#D8EDFF;border-radius: 20px;">Why can I sometimes see the moon during the day?</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use negative margins on interior elements to shift the prefixes. You'd then use a matching positive margin on the list. I'm using `em` elements to try and account for varying font sizes. You should test well. Maybe `rem` units would be better.

```html
<ol style="max-width:7cm; margin-left: 5.5em;">
  <li style="border: 2.0px dotted rgb(187,187,187);padding: 2.0mm;margin-bottom: 7.0mm;background: rgb(238,238,238);border-radius: 20px;">
    <span style="margin-left: -90px; margin-right: 25px;">Question</span> 
    Why is the sky blue?
  </li>
    
  <li style="border: 2.0px dotted rgb(187,187,187);padding: 2.0mm;margin-bottom: 7.0mm;background: rgb(238,238,238);border-radius: 20px;">
    <span style="margin-left: -5.5em; margin-right: 25px;">Question</span> 
    How many teeth does an adult human have?
  </li>
  
  <li style="border: 2.0px dotted rgb(187,187,187);padding: 2.0mm;margin-bottom: 7.0mm;background: rgb(238,238,238);border-radius: 20px;">
    <span style="margin-left: -5.5em; margin-right: 25px;">Question</span> 
    Why do birds fly south in the winter?
  </li>
  
  <li style="border: 2.0px dotted rgb(187,187,187);padding: 2.0mm;margin-bottom: 7.0mm;background: rgb(238,238,238);border-radius: 20px;">
    <span style="margin-left: -5.5em; margin-right: 25px;">Question</span>
    Why do birds fly south in the winter?
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Good answer. This solves the problem "visually". I was just hoping for a cleaner / more elegant solution that would not involve the repetition of the word "question" in each element.

Comment: As you've discovered, options are limited in email. They're usually ugly.

Comment: This only works on Apple/iPhones and Samsung. Gmail, Outlook (desktop, iOS, android) outlook.com, yahoo and others are all over the place, unfortunately. Most of them have the "Question" within the grey part. Outlook desktop is just a total mess.

Answer (score 2):

For customisations like this which are cross-email compatible, you will have to break semantics and use a table.

```
<table style="width:100%;max-width:500px;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:30px;vertical-align: middle" width="30"><p style="margin:0;font-size:14px;margin-bottom:25px;">Question&nbsp;1:</p>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top"><p style="margin:0;font-size:14px;border: 2px dotted rgb(187,187,187);padding: 10px;margin-bottom: 25px;background: rgb(238,238,238);border-radius: 20px;">Why is the sky blue?</p>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:30px;vertical-align: middle" width="30"><p style="margin:0;font-size:14px;margin-bottom:25px;">Question&nbsp;2:</p>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top"><p style="margin:0;font-size:14px;border: 2px dotted rgb(187,187,187);padding: 2.0mm;margin-bottom: 25px;background: rgb(238,238,238);border-radius: 20px;">Why is the sky blue?</p>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:30px;vertical-align: middle" width="30"><p style="margin:0;font-size:14px;margin-bottom:25px;">Question&nbsp;3:</p>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top"><p style="margin:0;font-size:14px;border: 2px dotted rgb(187,187,187);padding: 2.0mm;margin-bottom: 25px;background: rgb(238,238,238);border-radius: 20px;">Why is the sky blue?</p>
</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This won't achieve rounded corners in Outlook (there are plenty of answered questions on SO, or elsewhere on that).

But it shows a lot better in Gmail and others (first is this; second is @isherwood's)

[image: Gmail App render]

And in Outlook Windows:

[image: Outlook Windows render]

Comment: .  +1 thanks for the comparison screenshot. I'm astonished that there is no solution for a html list.

Comment: HTML email is an absolute beast :). Email software has to display a wide variety of code on their platform so they are very protective of what they allow and don't, and everyone does it differently.

Comment: Why do mail clients have to be more protective than web browsers ?

Comment: I think because it's about pulling in other people's HTML, which carries security risks. So they parse it very carefully

Comment: *"it's about pulling in other people's HTML"*: exactly what a web browser does also

Comment: But when you make a webpage you get it exact. When you have an email program, you are getting in sloppy HTML

Comment: I thought this was interesting too: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/134520/why-dont-web-email-clients-put-emails-in-an-iframe

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you're designing a email you can do it with inline css. Here's an example code for you:

```
<ul>
  <li>Question 1</li>
  <li>Question 2</li>
  <li>Question 3</li>
</ul>
```

I don't see any need to write pseudo-elements in emails.

Comment: This doesn't achieve the needed results. I updated the question to show.